# Limit solving without using L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How can I solve this limit

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x+1}-e}{3x} $$

without using L'Hopital's rule?

I know this is true:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} = 1 $$

So i belive we have to use this in anyway possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of derivative? How do you define exponential function? Please add such context to your question.

Comment: I am familiar with that concept but the exercise must not be resolved that way. I believe we have to use this $$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} = 1 $$

Comment: What do you mean, "that way"? The equality you wrote in your comment is simply the derivative of $e^x$ when $x=0$.

Comment: @JoãoSilva if you already know that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}$$ then factor $\frac{e}{3}$ out in front of the limit.

Comment: My doubt is how you take out the +1 on e^x+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^{x+1} - e }{3x} = \dfrac{e}{3} \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = \dfrac{e}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x+1}-e}{3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e\cdot e^x-e}{3x}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e}{3}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac{e}{3}$$

Remember that, if $\ a\in \mathbb R$  then $\ a^{x+y}=a^x\cdot a^y$

Comment: This is the solution, my doubt is how you took the +1 on e^x+1.

Comment: @JoãoSilva That is how exponents work. $a \cdot a^ x = a^1\cdot a^x = a^{x+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** You can use the infinite series expansion of $e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$

Comment: No thanks. $ $ $ $

Comment: I have never heard of this concept, so I dont think it can be used.

Comment: Have you not heard of the infnite series expansion or the approach to use that in the limit?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{e^x - e^{x_0}}{x-x_0}=(e^x)_{x=x_0}'=e^{x_0}$

Then I would say

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x+1}-e}{3x}=\frac{e}{3}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}=\frac{e}{3}\cdot (e^x)'_{x=0}=\frac{e}{3}$